# No output has been received in the last 10 minutes, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself

Tags: travis-ci

I can't get through the whole build process due to the error reported in the subject.
My build is https://travis-ci.org/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator/jobs/72481328.
Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let you know, I added the vendor directory in the phpunit file and I did some performance optimizations. But I think the vendor had to be ignored otherwise it parses it and it took a longer time as I added new dependencies...